# override css of grandparent from child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code structure:-

```
<li class="container">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="green">...</div>
  </div>
</li>


<li class="container">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="xyz">...</div>
  </div>
</li>


..
.. so on
```

Now li has the following css :-

```
margin-top:35px
```

I don't want to inherit the above margin for li which contains the class **green** but I want it for the class **xyz**.

I have tried using operator **>** in css but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post more CSS? You have only provided one rule which don't help much.

Comment: You'll need selectors level 4 to do that in pure CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont want `margin-top:35px` to be applied (inherit from parent li) to `div.green` then here is the solution

**CSS**

```
.green {
  margin-top:-35px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<li class="container">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="green">...</div>
  </div>
</li>


<li class="container">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="xyz">...</div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:has()` jQuery pseudo selector:

```
$('.container:has(.xyz)').css(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

With this code structure, assuming a parent container:

```
<ul>
    <li class="container">
      <div class="wrap">
        <div class="green">...</div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="container">
      <div class="wrap">
        <div class="xyz">...</div>
      </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You could do this:

```
ul li:nth-child(2) {
   margin: 0;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

But a rule to "If I have inside a div with xyz class then..." I think it is impossible in pure css.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

There is no parent selector in css but you can use javascript:

```
$('.xyz').closest('.container').css('margin-top', '35px');
```

Comment: I think you mean jquery (not javascript). alternatively, you can use .parent()

Comment: well, you can also do it in js without jquery, of course

Comment: @tribe84 jQuery is javascript.

Comment: No, it's not. Its a framework or library build on top of javascript to make accessing the DOM more manageable. It's like calling bootstrap css.

Comment: @tribe84 it's written in javascript so it's javascript not css.

Comment: It's still not javascript. Javascript is a language. When you provide your answer, someone might be mistaken to think that the $ selector is part of the javascript language, which it is not. In fact, $, .closest, .css are all element of jquery which is not something that is inherently javascript.